# Set default application configs for Elixir packages

Tags: elixir

I'm writing an Elixir package, and I want to specify a default application configuration (that the user can override by specifying custom values in their `config.exs`). I was originally putting them in my project's `config.exs` until I realized that the config file won't be loaded for projects that depend on this library.

The config file itself tells you that:

> This configuration is loaded before any dependency and is restricted 
>   to this project. If another project depends on this project, this 
>   file won't be loaded nor affect the parent project. For this reason, 
>   if you want to provide default values for your application for 
>   3rd-party users, it should be done in your "mix.exs" file.

---

I've been struggling to understand how to specify application defaults in my `mix.exs` and use them. My current solution is to use [`Application.get_env/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#get_env/3) with a default argument but that doesn't seem right to me as the application defaults would be scattered through out the code.

```
Application.get_env(:my_library, :arg, "default value")
```

**So, How can I specify application defaults in `mix.exs`?**

Comment: The other way round: one does [`Application.put_env/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#put_env/4) and later on the main application would read and/or overwrite those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set default config values for your application in `mix.exs` - these will also be available when used as dependency in another project. For example:

```
def applications do
  [applications: [:logger, ...],
   mod: {MyLibrary.Application, []},
   env: [arg: "default value"]]
end
```