# How to deal with multiple application config files in elixir umbrella application

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have an elixir umbrella application (A) which has multiple applications underneath. One of them (B) is defined is separate repository and contains its own config (`config/config.exs`) file, mostly with default values.

When adding application B to A and starting umbrella application, configuration for application B is not loaded. It looks like I need to explicitly include all configuration params for B in A config.

I would expect that config for application B will be still available in application A and I would only have to override some specific values.

Could anyone explain to me how I can achieve it without specifying all config params again in main application (A) config file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An umbrella application generated with `mix new --umbrella` should automatically include the configs of all applications.

In `your_project/apps/app_a/mix.exs` it should be configured to read the config from the umbrella root:

```
 build_path: "../../_build",
 config_path: "../../config/config.exs",
 deps_path: "../../deps",
 lockfile: "../../mix.lock",
```

And in `your_project/config/config.exs`, it should include all apps config:

```
use Mix.Config

# By default, the umbrella project as well as each child
# application will require this configuration file, ensuring
# they all use the same configuration. While one could
# configure all applications here, we prefer to delegate
# back to each application for organization purposes.
import_config "../apps/*/config/config.exs"
```

Comment: thanks. How would it work for the application included as a dependency instead of being inlined in `apps` directory?

Comment: Ah sorry, to set a default in one package to be used in another, put the values in `mix.exs`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43304305/1650580